# Hugo: Access template variables in JS files

Tags: javascript, html, hugo

In my Hugo website, baseUrl is set to: website.com/variable.

If an image element is in .html (< img src="/images/image.png" >), the baseUrl is applied and the final url is this: website.com/variable/images/image.png/

If an image element is in .js (img.src = "/images/image.png"), the baseUrl is not applied and the final url is incorrect: website.com/images/image.png/

I tried to add a custom output format for js in config.toml, but it didn't work:
[mediaTypes."application/javascript"]
suffixes = ["js"]

Is there a way to access template variables in .js files?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
{{ $js := resources.Get "js/main.js" | js.Build (dict "params" (dict "api" "https://example.org/api")) }}
```

Then in your JS file:

```
import * as params from '@params';
```

For example, I have this in one of my sites:

```
{{- $msftclarityjs := resources.Get "js/analytics-msftclarity.js" | js.Build ( dict "params" ( dict "msftclarityid" $msftclarityid ) ) -}}
```

Then in the analytics-msftclarift.js file I have this:

```
import * as params from '@params';

…

(window, document, "clarity", "script", params.msftclarityid);
```

See Hugo docs [JavaScript Building](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/js/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:
"Is there a way to access template variables in .js files?"
No, as Hugo builds, then Hugo's template codes no longer exist. JS runs on the built site.

To answer your other question:
"If an image element is in .html (< img src="/images/image.png" >), the baseUrl is applied and the final url is this: website.com/variable/images/image.png/"

"If an image element is in .js (img.src = "/images/image.png"), the baseUrl is not applied and the final url is incorrect: website.com/images/image.png/"

I would suggest you use image processing and generate the full links, and then you can access/no deal with your image links, but I would need more data about your set-up. Hopefully that gives you enough to work with.